# ViewPager + PagerAdapter w/ Pagination not working properly

Tags: android, pagination, android-viewpager, android-pageradapter

I have a gallery/slideshow activity that allows user to swipe between Photos. Each "Page" is just a [TouchImageView](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView). There is a pagination logic in there, and I can see that it is calling the API accordingly. However, I am not able to swipe further even after notifyDataSetChanged has been called. Here's the code:

```
Activity {
    ViewPager vp;
    CustomPagerAdapter pagerAdapter;

    onCreate() {
        //api callback
        pagerAdapter = new CustomPagerAdapter();
        vp.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    }
}

CustomPagerAdapter() {
    TouchImageView imageView;
    List<Photos> photos;

    int getCount() {
        return photos == null ? 0 : photos.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pager_image, container, false);
        imageView = (TouchImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.photo);
        Glide.with(context)
                .load(photos.get(position).getUrl())
                .into(imageView);

        container.addView(itemView);

        if (position == photos.size()-1) {
            loadMorePhotos();
        }

        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((RelativeLayout) object);
    }

    void loadMorePhotos() {
        //call api and stuff
        void onResponse(Call call, Response<List<Photo>> response) {
            photos.addAll(response.body);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Pf31.jpg

I have no idea what is going on for 2 days. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

This may not be ideal, but where you call `notifyDatasetChanged()` you could instead try calling `vp.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);`

(i.e. actually re-set the adapter). A downside of this is that the pager will probably go back to having the first page selected. To avoid this, you'd need to save the latest page somewhere and restore it afterwards.

As I say, not ideal, but it may help.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to load more photos from adapter class, in your activity class you can use `onPageScrolled` and call the api when the last item is scrolled and set adapter again also save state of view pager before calling api to retain it when adapter is set again.

```
    private boolean isLastPageSwiped;
    private int counterPageScroll;

private OnPageChangeListener mListener = new OnPageChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     if (position == 6 && positionOffset == 0 && !isLastPageSwiped){
        if(counterPageScroll != 0){
            isLastPageSwiped=true;
            //call api 
        }
        counterPageScroll++;
    }else{
        counterPageScroll=0;
    }

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
};
```

and use this listener

```
vp.setOnPageChangeListener(mListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use this approach for doing pagination on ViewPager (with fragment)

1. load new page data but not append to the adapter
2. make sure the page is not scrolling, then append new page data into the adapter (`ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener#onPageScrolled's positionOffsetPixels == 0`).
3. update current item for view pager with offset = new page data's size (let's call it `newPosition`)
4. rebind data to 3 fragments: `newPosition - 1`, `newPosition`, `newPosition + 1`

For getting current fragment, we can use fragment manager

```
    private fun getFragment(position: Int): PageFragment? =
        supportFragmentManager.fragments.firstOrNull {
            (it as? PageFragment)?.position == position // always pass possition value into the fragment
        } as? PageFragment
```

We need to append data when not scrolling (step 2) to have a better UX to users. If we append data immediately when it comes and if user is scrolling, view pager's `setCurrentItem` will make a strange move.

I create a simple version here https://github.com/tuanchauict/DemoPaginationViewPager. Please take a look